# Triple Loop performance Issue

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I have the following code, it loops over an oracle forms block and then compares it with data from a cursor (the cursor takes data from the block itself). due to the three loops the performance is pretty bad and grows exponentially with lots of records. Any advice on how to improve it?

```
loop
    if :PAYMENTS_COLLECTIONS.CHECK_BOX='Y' then
        temp_rec := :system.cursor_record;
        acc_payment_no1 := :payments_collections.acc_payment_numb;

        for pay_same_trans in payments_in_same_trans(:payments_collections.acc_payment_numb) 
        loop
            first_record;
            acc_payment_no2 := pay_same_trans.acc_payment_no;

            REMOVE_PAID_TRANSACTION(pay_same_trans.payment_trans_seq_no);
            loop
                if pay_same_trans.acc_payment_no = :PAYMENTS_COLLECTIONS.acc_payment_numb and :PAYMENTS_COLLECTIONS.CHECK_BOX='Y' then
                    receipt_selected := true;
                    exit;
                end if;
                if :system.last_record = 'TRUE' then
                  exit;
                end if; 
                next_record;
            end loop;
            if receipt_selected = false then
                raise not_reverting_whole_trans;
            end if;
            receipt_selected := false;
        end loop;
        go_record(temp_rec);
    end if;
    if :system.last_record = 'TRUE' then
      exit;
    end if; 
    next_record;
end loop;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could post all block data to the db in a temp table, then run a procedure to check the data with **joins**, which will be orders of magnitude more efficient than your logic.

Then insert/delete/update in the final tables as per your business requirement, then re-query the block from db.

You'll have to rewrite pretty much all your logic but you'll have created a nice interface in PL/SQL that you will be able to reuse the day you drop Forms for something else.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The code above is in the form itself. The data in the block is based on several search fields within the form. Is there a way to optimize this while keeping everything within the form?

Comment: What's more important to you: performance or where the code is placed?

Comment: performance is key however the code is part of a bigger much complex code within the form ...

Comment: You're trying to do set logic (find rows in this dataset which are not in this other dataset but are in yet another dataset) with Forms, most likely you'll end up with complex, hard-to-maintain and ineffective code. Sometimes tools are not suited to every task. I personally find that Forms should not perform data logic, because PL/SQL is a lot more efficient to deal with data and doesn't add a level of cache and complexity.